# Read X records from the end of a file

Tags: php

I have a logging script which saves to file logs.
I would like to know how I can read X amount of records from the end of the file without pulling all the data from the file.

This is an example of a record in the file:

> [02.10.2011, 23:15:09] User 'dor' added comment.

This is the insertion code:

```
public function logError( string $errorMessage )
{
    if( emtpy( trim( $errorMessage ) ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    $errorMessage = trim( strip_tags( htmlspecialchars( $errorMessage ) ) );
    $errorTime = date( 'd.m.Y, H:i:s' );

    $errorRow = "[{$errorTime}] {$errorMessage}\n";

    if( @is_writable( "{$this->logsDir}{$this->logFile}" ) )
    {
        if( fwrite( $this->fileHandler , $errorRow) === false )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `fseek` function with negative *offset* and `SEEK_END` as *whence*

Look into documentation of `fseek` http://php.net/fseek

Comment: Sample of how to do this present in comments to documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php#106336

Comment: Did you followed the link in my comment above? The sample in comments on php.net (now it's a second from top) provide function that do exactly what you wanted